# Comando "npm" não é reconhecido pelo Prompt de Comando

Tags: node.js, cmd

Tenho um projeto com um `package.json`, nele eu tenho tudo configurado.

Apenas fiz o clone desse mesmo projeto em outra maquina, meu `git clone` funcionou sem problemas.

Mas ao eu dar o comando `npm install` no CMD para incluir os módulos que vou usar, a seguinte mensagem aparece:

> 'npm' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
>   ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional?

Answer (score 15):

Consigo enxergar dois possíveis problemas:

1. O NodeJS não está instalado
2. O NodeJS não está na variável `PATH` de ambiente do Windows

No segundo caso tente adicionar `C:/Program Files/nodejs` (ou o diretório onde o Node foi instalado) à variável de ambiente.

Veja: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4356

Comment: Ou qualquer outro caminho q você tenha instalado o seu node

Comment: Então, eu verifiquei minhas variáveis de ambiente, e estavam certar.. eu acredito que era algo na rede. eu estava em casa e não estava funcionando. Quando cheguei na faculdade, e executei o "npm install" ele baixou as dependencias.. Mas valeu cara!

Answer (score 4):

Instale o node.js na maquina de destino da sua app, isto resolverá seu problema.

Answer (score 4):

No Windows 64 Bits - Pt.Br: 
 Abra o Executar e digite: 
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe 
 No Prompt de Comando que se abrir, digite: 
 CD .. 
 CD .. 
 CD Arquivos de Programas 
 CD nodejs 
 npm install -g phonegap

Answer (score 3):

Se o node estiver instalado e ainda sim o npm não estiver sendo reconhecido é bem provável (por algum motivo) que o path do sistema não tenha sido atualizado.

no prompt de comando (CMD) digite " npm config get prefix " para verificar onde está a pasta do npm, por exemplo: "C:\Users\"seu nome de usuario"\AppData\Roaming\npm" e adicione essa informação no path.

para alterar o path, com o explorador de arquivo aberto,clique com o botão direito em "Este computador", na janela do sistema clique em "Configurações avançadas do sistema", em propriedades do sistema clica em "Variáveis de Ambiente" abra a variável "Path", clique em "Novo" e adicione o caminho do npm.

espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Tente o seguinte comando:

```
node -v
```

Pro caso da versão não ser exibida, faça a instalação do node. Tive o mesmo problema e assim que instalei, precisei reiniciar o projeto no vs code.