# Cordova - Erro - Cordova Platform add android

Tags: javascript, html5, mobile, apache-cordova

Fiz a instalação do cordova, instalei  a SDK do android, mas na hora que  boto o comando  Cordova Platform add android ele da o seguinte erro.

http://prntscr.com/49brfk

vi no docs do cordova que preciso adicionar  algo ao PATH

> You may need to add the npm directory to your PATH in order to invoke globally installed npm modules. On Windows, npm can usually be found at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm.

alguem ja teve esse problema?

Comment: Sim, já tive esse problema. Verifica se tens: JAVA_HOME definido no teu PATH, se instalaste mesmo o NodeJS - (para teres acesso ao NPM). 
Verifica também se tens o SDK do Android no teu PATH e se o emulador está funcional.
Aconselho a veres os vídeos do learn: http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/
Tens aqui, passo a passo, como instalar bem como a ultrapassares os erros mais comuns!

Comment: Acredito que esta resposta irá te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19024/5536. Para utilizar o PhoneGap você precisa ter no seu path o caminho para o Java, para o NodeJs e para o ApacheAnt e ter configurado o SDK do android. Siga as instruções do [Getting Started do PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá parece que você tem que executar no terminal(cmd) o comando Android caso já tenha instalado o SDK do Android e definido a variável de ambiente `ANDROID_HOME`.
Na janela que aparecer você tem que baixar o *build tools* e uma API por exemplo: API Level 20.

Em seguida tente novamente adicionar a plataforma no Cordova.